# Does a Split Central AC condenser circuit breaker need to be GFCI protected?

Tags: circuit-breaker

Is the sub-panel circuit breaker feeding a disconnect to a 3 ton AC Condenser required to be a GFCI breaker, or just a standard 30A double pole breaker.

Answer (score 3):

### A standard breaker will do just fine

Since a condensing unit isn't a dishwasher or a boat hoist, and it does not plug into a 120V or 240V, 15 or 20A receptacle, it does not fall into any of the categories listed in 210.8 that apply to dwelling units.  This means that GFCI protection is not required, and you can safely use a standard circuit breaker of the appropriate type as a result.